# Bubble sort. Do I need double or int?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

OK So I am making a bubble sorting program to make sure arrays are in order and I have the first class compiled fine now but the second one keeps giving me problems.  Right now it says it is the wrong type so I changed the variable dif  to a int instead of a double but then it says possible loss of precision.   Here is the code for the first file.

```
public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void sort(int[] a, int numberUsed)
    {
        int index;
        for ( int i =0; i<numberUsed; i++)
        {
            for (index = 0; index<a.length - 1; index++)
            {
                if (a[index]> a[index + 1])
                {
                    interchange(index, index + 1, a);
                } //end of if ()
            } //end of for ()
        } //end of for ()
    }
        private static void interchange(int i, int j, int[] a)
        {
            int temp1;
            temp1 = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp1;
        }
    }
```

and this is the second file that is giving me the problem

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GolfScores
{
    public static double[] diff = new double[5];
    public static void printOutArray(double[] a)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorted array values:");
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%2.2f",a[i]);
        } //end of for loop
        System.out.println();
        double Handicap= (diff[0])/1*0.96;
        System.out.printf("Handicap: %2.2f",Handicap);
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //construct and declare three arrays
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] rating = new double[5];
        double[] slope = new double[5];
        double[] score = new double[5];
        int numberUsed = 0;
        int index = 0;

        //Print out directions for the user
        System.out.println("Calculate handicap for 5 games of golf.  This program takes Scores, \nCourse Rating and Slope rating for 5 games. \n\nUsing those figures, the program calculates the differential\nfor each round entered using this formula:(Score - Course Rating) x113 / Slope Rating.  \n\nThen uses the lowest differential to calculate handicap");
        System.out.println();
        //A do while loop that runs until index is great than 5
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter golf scores for game " +(index+1)+ ": ");
            score[index]= keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Course rating for game "+(index+1)+ ": ");
            rating[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Course slope for game "+(index+1)+": ");
            slope[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            index++;
            //index is the number of array indexed variables used so far
        } while((index<5));
        //this formula for all 5 arrays (Score- Course Rating) x 113 / Slope Rating
        diff[0]=((score[0]- rating[0]) * 113 / slope [0]);
        diff[1]=((score[1]-rating[1])*113/slope[1]);
        diff[2]=((score[2]-rating[2])*113/slope[2]);
        diff[3]=((score[3]-rating[3])*113/slope[3]);
        diff[4]=((score[4]-rating[4])*113/slope[4]);

        BubbleSort.sort(diff, diff.length);//passes value of diff array to BubbleSort.sort
        printOutArray(diff);//prints out diff array
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use bubblesort.  It's a toy sort, used for "baby's first sort program", after which it should be forgotten and never used again.  Whatever language you're using probably has other built-in sorts.  Use them.

Comment: @Paul : I would assume this is a homework assignment, and calling Arrays.sort is not allowed.

Comment: Once more, if it's homework it would be REALLY NICE if the poster would tag or mentions so so that we can give an accurately targeted answer.  Anyone who answers this question (as phrased) with anything but "Use arrays.sort" is wrong if it's not tagged as homework.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I hope I will remember to better label my question next time.  I noticed a few things I left out that I could have put in.

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble sort only works on int[], thus the diff must be int[].

And I think the "possible loss of precision" comes from

```
    diff[0]=((score[0]- rating[0]) * 113 / slope [0]);
    diff[1]=((score[1]-rating[1])*113/slope[1]);
    diff[2]=((score[2]-rating[2])*113/slope[2]);
    diff[3]=((score[3]-rating[3])*113/slope[3]);
    diff[4]=((score[4]-rating[4])*113/slope[4]);
```

Because:

```
    double[] rating = new double[5];
    double[] slope = new double[5];
    double[] score = new double[5];
```

Those arrays are defined as double[].

And What datatype you need depends on what your input will be.
If the input is nothing more than int, then use int. If floating-point number might appear, double should be considered.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem and I had to change a few other double parts as well but I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the data types match, as mentioned before your BubbleSort class operates only on an int array, this is the code as modified to work with double arrays (which is what diff contains).

When you changed dif to an int and received the "loss of precision" message, it's because you're doing division (lines 43-47 in GolfScores.java) and then assigning the result to an int (which discards fractional values).

Here is a version of BubbleSort that compiles without errors or warnings. Changes I made (there are 3 of them) are noted as comments:

```
public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void sort(double[] a, int numberUsed) //change here
    {
        int index;
        for ( int i =0; i<numberUsed; i++)
        {
            for (index = 0; index<a.length - 1; index++)
            {
                if (a[index]> a[index + 1])
                {
                    interchange(index, index + 1, a);
                } //end of if ()
            } //end of for ()
        } //end of for ()
    }
        private static void interchange(int i, int j, double[] a) //change here
        {
            double temp1; //change here, important
            temp1 = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp1;
        }
    }
```

The code could be made more flexible by using objects instead of primitive types (like, sort an array of Object instead of double), and perhaps using a user-specified function to compare elements, this way you wouldn't need to change the class to handle different data types. That said, if you're going to use many more of Java's facilities and standard libraries, you might as well go the Arrays.sort method. [This page](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html) explains use of built-in sort methods (as well as why you shouldn't write your own sort routines *unless* it's some sort of academic assignments) better than I can.